# dynamically create table rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-tables

I have multiple tables in my page, in which user will add new rows as per his need.

I have successfully created a function which takes the table id and then add new row to that specific table.

But i need to add the delete functionality as well.

**This is my HTML Table**

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered order-list" id="educationTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Institute Name</th>
            <th>Qualification</th>
            <th>Admission Date</th>
            <th>Graduation Date</th>
            <th>Degree Scanned Image</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="educationTableBody">
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt[]" id="number" />
            </td>
            <td><i id="add" class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x fa-fw" onclick="insTableRow('educationTable')"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**insTableRow function**

```
function insTableRow(tableID) {
    var x=document.getElementById(tableID);
    var get_row = x.rows[1];
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    $("#"+tableID+" tbody").append(new_row);
}
```

What I want now, that if users click on add new row icon , a new row should be added with eopty input values, and in previous row, add new row icon should be replaced with delete this row icon, and on delete row it should delete the row.

Any idea how can I achieve this ?

working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e2kw71kf/)

Comment: you could keep the new row hidden, and copy it and make it visible when you click the button. Obviously it should have the delete row button already there, and it should execute a function that would hide that row.

Comment: I would unlock this question since it's absolutely not a duplicate of the question linked, the questions are way too different. Please, unlock it.

Comment: @Shinratensei I will try to do what u proposed. and will post the answer

Comment: you won't be able to, the question is now blocked and can't receive answers

Comment: this is not fair

Comment: I know, if somebody else with a gold badge sees this they might be able to help

Comment: ok, please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e2kw71kf/ I am haiving issue on showing hidden row. any idea ?

Comment: important thing: you're mixing pure javascript and jQuery, don't do that, try to use only jQuery. And yes, I have an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/f6h2rs9d/